# Declare new modules by a string

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

**Background:**
I write a data sync application in ruby between two remote systems. 
It should be used for multiple clients with a similar functionality. My idea was to implement a default module and load this module in the application initialize process in a client namespace module (and maybe include additional custom client classes that extend the standard functionality).

**generic.rb**

```
module DemoClass
  class A
    def demo1
      puts "Generic::A"
    end
  end

  class B
    def demo1
      puts "Generic::B"
    end
  end
end
```

in the initialize process, clients declare a new namespace and include the default functions.

but how can declare a new module by a string?

```
module ClientA
  require 'generic.rb'
end

module ClientB
  require 'generic.rb'

  module DemoClass
    class B
      def demo1
        puts "Client2::DemoClass:B"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Using `require` inside a `module` block is not different than using the same `require` outside of it

Comment: but i like to define the module names (Client1,Client2) by strings in the bootstrap process, maybe i have ~100 different clients